# QuickSmoke fire effect not appearing in render

Tags: rendering, effects

I'm trying to add fire and smoke to my scene. I decided to use QuickEffects > QuickSmoke, and then change the flow type to `Fire + Smoke` on my emitter. It seems that both the fire and smoke appear in the scene view, however only the smoke appears in the render. (using Cycles)

Scene view:

[image]

Render:

[image]

*(the smoke is a bit hard to see on the black background)*

If required, I can share the settings of the smoke emitter and the smoke domain.

Thanks in advance.